# JavaFX : Not on FX application thread error occurs

Tags: java, javafx

I want to pop up the progressindecator while some tasks are working. In order to do this, I coded my program like the followings..

```
public void handleCheckButtonOnAction(Button button, DBConnect conn) {
    ProgressForm pForm = new ProgressForm();
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
            checkTargetDatabaseInfo();
            updateProgress(-1, -1);
            return null;
        }
    };
    pForm.activateProgressBar(task);
    task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
        pForm.getDialogStage().close();
    });

    pForm.getDialogStage().show();

    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();
}
```

There is a function which to change a label inside checkTargetDatabaseInfo method.

and the error like this..

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
    at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
    at managerworld.controller.SetEnvironmentViewerController.checkTargetDatabaseInfo(SetEnvironmentViewerController.java:142)
    at managerworld.controller.SetEnvironmentViewerController.access$600(SetEnvironmentViewerController.java:42)
    at managerworld.controller.SetEnvironmentViewerController$1.call(SetEnvironmentViewerController.java:109)
    at managerworld.controller.SetEnvironmentViewerController$1.call(SetEnvironmentViewerController.java:98)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You must not call a UI method (`Labeled.setText()`) from within the Task thread. Instead, store the result of your `checkTargetDatabaseInfo` call and update the UI in a Task handler like `setOnSucceed`.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html:  `Because the Task is designed for use with JavaFX GUI applications, it ensures that every change to its public properties, as well as change notifications for state, errors, and for event handlers, all occur on the main JavaFX application thread.`

Comment: Andreas your comment is an answer, please make it so.

Comment: @Andreas but how about the other UI method like a circle? I changed the color of a circle in checkTargetDatabaseInfo method.

Comment: @Andreas You're right Andreas. I had tested several times and I have got that there's no way to change UI which located the parent scene through Task. On the other hand, Andreas, what do you think of using Platform.runlater method? Do you think it is possible to update UI with pop up window progress bar? I now have no idea how to carry on with this. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andreas, I finally find the answer myself, anyway it's so thankful and your comment would very helpful for me.

I inserted some code which update UI method into Platform.runLater method and it worked fine. Here's my code..

```
private void checkDBVersion () {
        ProgressForm pForm = new ProgressForm();
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                SimpleStringProperty version = new SimpleStringProperty();
                Connection targetDBconn = null;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;

                try {
                    targetDBconn = globalTargetConn.connect();
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){@Override public void run() {logWriter.writeLogs(logTextArea, LogWriter.INFO, "Checking this database version...");}});
                    pstmt = new LoggableStatement(targetDBconn, SqlList.checkTargetDBVersionSQL);
                    String SQL = ((LoggableStatement) pstmt).getQueryString();
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){@Override public void run() {logWriter.writeLogs(logTextArea, LogWriter.INFO, "See the query below...");}});
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){@Override public void run() {logWriter.writeLogs(logTextArea, LogWriter.INFO, SQL);}});
                    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        version.set(rs.getString(1));
                        targetDatabaseInfo.setVersion(version);
                    }
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){@Override public void run() {logWriter.writeLogs(logTextArea, LogWriter.INFO, "Your database version is " + version.getValue());}});
                } catch (SQLException ex) {Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){@Override public void run() {logWriter.writeLogs(logTextArea, LogWriter.ERROR, ex.getMessage());}}); 
                } finally {
                    if (rs != null ) try {rs.close();} catch(SQLException ex) {}
                    if (pstmt != null ) try {pstmt.close();} catch(SQLException ex) {}
                    if (targetDBconn != null ) try {targetDBconn.close();} catch(SQLException ex) {}
                }
                _DB_VERSION = version;
                updateProgress(-1, -1);
                return null;
            }
        };
        pForm.activateProgressBar(task);
        task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            pForm.getDialogStage().close();
        });
        pForm.getDialogStage().show();
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();
    }
```

After this is done, I'm just curious whether is the background job and not. Is progress bar background job??